# Problem comparing Strings in vba for excel

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to make a excel macro to parse xls to xml and in certain parts of my code I need to compare strings and I do not know why it does not work. This is the code:

```
Set newAtributte = oXMLFile.createAttribute("display")
            newAtributte.Value = Cells(i, 2)
            Debug.Print TypeName(newAtribute.Value)
            Debug.Print newAtribute.Value
            Debug.Print TypeName(Cells(i, 2).Value)
            Debug.Print Cells(i, 2).Value
            Debug.Print TypeName("Integer")
            'If Cells(i, 2).Value = "String" Then newField.Text = StringID
            If StrComp(Cells(i, 2).Value, "Integer") = 0 Then Debug.Print "He entrado en el if"
            'If Cells(i, 2).Value = "Floating point number" Then newField.Text = FloatingPointNumberID
            'If Cells(i, 2).Value = "Boolean" Then newField.Text = BooleanID
```

And this is the debug exit:

```
String
Integer 
String
Integer
```

I do not know why it does not go inside the if.

Comment: Note: I'm just assuming `Intgeger` is a spelling error....? Also, you are comparing the value to `Integer` currently, and not the TypeName. So maybe `If StrComp(TypeName(Cells(i, 2).Value), "Integer") = 0 Then...` is what you are after

Comment: *It does not work* is unclear. Could you please be more specific? Also, you are using the default compare (binary), so it is case sensitive. If you want to compare just text, then it should be `StrComp(Cells(i, 2).Value, "Intgeger",1) = 0`

Comment: @JvdV yes is aspellin erro y try with all the options of the strcomp and it does not retur true

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns  I am trying to compare de value of te `cell(i,2)`which is the strin "Integer" with the string "Integer"and it does not work because it should return true and print on the debug `He entrado en el if` ant it does not do.

Comment: What do you get if you put `Debug.Print Len(Cells(i, 2).Value)`? Also, did you tried with `StrComp(Cells(i, 2).Value, "Integer",1)`?

Comment: Thank ypu for all the help I already solve it